# confusion understanding a processor?

Tags: embedded, signal-processing, microprocessor, processor

As shown highlighted in attached photo,In case of 6713 dsp,during each clock cycle, up to eight instructions can be carried out in parallel

Does this happen in case of every processor that multiple instructions can be carried out in parallel in one clock cycle? What about general purpose processor like 8086?How many instructions can be carried out in parallel in one clock cycle?
[image]

Comment: Not every processor, no.

Comment: Just faster processors. Slow devices may be limited to 1 or even fewer instructions per cycle.

Answer (score 4):

The TMS320C6713 floating-point digital signal processor uses the C67x VelociTI AdvancedVery-Long Instruction Words (VLIW) CPU. The CPU fetches (256 bits wide) to supply up to eight 32-bit instructions to the eight functional units during every clock cycle. The VelociTI VLIWarchitecture also features variable-length execute packets; these variable-length executepackets are a key memory-saving feature, distinguishing the C67x CPU from other VLIWarchitectures.
So no, this is very specific to this particular processor from this vendor ... Others may have similar specs...